# Is there a sequence with the largest length satisfying certain conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

**Find the maximum $n$ that meets the following conditions:**

There is a sequence $a_1,a_2\cdots a_n$, satisfied, for any $s ∈ [1, n]$, $a_1,a_2\cdots a_s$ belongs to $(0,1/s), (1/s,2/s)\cdots((s − 1)/s, 1)$ these $s$ intervals (not required to be in order).

**If there is no maximum $n$, the next problem is:**

Is there a sequence $a_1,a_2\cdots $, satisfied, for any $s ∈ N^+$,$a_1,a_2\cdots a_s$ belongs to $(0,1/s), (1/s,2/s)\cdots((s − 1)/s, 1)$ these $s$ intervals (not required to be in order).

For example, when $n$=6,we can find one sequence $$(0/5,1/6) \ a_1=5$$
$$(1/5,1/4) \ a_2=3$$
$$(2/5,1/2) \ a_3=2$$
$$(3/6,4/6) \ a_4=6$$
$$(4/6,3/4) \ a_5=4$$
$$(5/6,1/1) \ a_6=1$$

*(I saw this problem in a Chinese BBS called **chaoli.club**,the user "鹿目まどか" asked this question. No one has answered yet.)*

Comment: It is the original problem's website  https://chaoli.club/index.php/6764

Comment: The largest n found by the questioner so far is 17. Maybe VPN is needed to log in to the above website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$17$ is the maximum. See Berlekamp, E. R. and Graham, R. L. "Irregularities in the Distributions of Finite Sequences." J. Number Th. 2, 152-161, 1970, and also https://mathworld.wolfram.com/18-PointProblem.html

[It appears that I already answered this question, four years ago: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708596/puzzle-reference-request-planting-trees-in-a-semicircle-orchard/2711466#2711466][1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708596/puzzle-reference-request-planting-trees-in-a-semicircle-orchard/2711466#2711466)

Comment: And here's another appearance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980396/are-there-any-non-casework-proofs-of-the-18-point-problem/3980413#3980413 and one more, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278383/a-golden-angle-conjecture/4285543#4285543

Comment: TY,.sir,I will delete it@Gerry Myerson

Comment: Why delete it??

Comment: Sorry, Professor, I thought I couldn't ask again if  the  question have a similar answer with others. Sorry, I won't delete the post.I used to ask same question before and was afraid of being voted.I sincerely appreciate your reply and forgive my poor English